# B-Ship: Alternating AI and User (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently making a b-ship game. I am trying to make it such that the user makes a hit then the ai, then the user, then the ai, etc. How can I manage that?

```
import random
import time

def drawboard(hitboard,hitboard2):
    print(' Opponent\'s          Your')
    print('    Ships            Ships')
    print('|   |   |   |    |   |   |   |')
    print('| ' + hitboard[7] + ' | ' + hitboard[8] + ' | ' + hitboard[9] + ' |    | ' + hitboard2[7] + ' | ' + hitboard2[8] + ' | ' + hitboard2[9] + ' |')
    print('|   |   |   |    |   |   |   |')
    print('-------------    -------------')
    print('|   |   |   |    |   |   |   |')
    print('| ' + hitboard[4] + ' | ' + hitboard[5] + ' | ' + hitboard[6] + ' |    | ' + hitboard2[4] + ' | ' + hitboard2[5] + ' | ' + hitboard2[6] + ' |')
    print('|   |   |   |    |   |   |   |')
    print('-------------    -------------')
    print('|   |   |   |    |   |   |   |')
    print('| ' + hitboard[1] + ' | ' + hitboard[2] + ' | ' + hitboard[3] + ' |    | ' + hitboard2[1] + ' | ' + hitboard2[2] + ' | ' + hitboard2[3] + ' |')
    print('|   |   |   |    |   |   |   |')
def aiships(hitboard,spot_hit,shipspots,hitboard2):
    if spot_hit in shipspots:
        hitboard[spot_hit] = 'x'
    else:
        hitboard[spot_hit] = 'o'
    drawboard(hitboard,hitboard2)

def middle(spot_hit, hitboard2):
    if spot_hit in usership:
        pass

def playerships(hitboard,hitboard2, x, usershipspots):
    drawboard(hitboard,hitboard2)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("\nComputer's turn.\n")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    if x in usershipspots:
        hitboard2[x] =='x'
        hitboard2[usershipspots[1]] = 'x'
        drawboard(hitboard,hitboard2)        
        return True #AI wins
    else:
        hitboard2[x] == 'o'
        drawboard(hitboard,hitboard2)
        return False #Player wins

def main():
    twoships = [[1,2], [2,1], [1,4], [4,1], [2,3], [3,2], [2,5], [5,2], [3,6], [6,3], [4,5], [5,4], [4,7], [7,4], [5,6], [6,5], [5,8], [8,5], [6,9], [9,6], [7,8], [8,7], [8,9], [9,8]]
    threeships = [[1,2,3], [1,3,2], [2,1,3], [2,3,1], [3,2,1], [3,1,2], [1,4,7], [1,7,4], [4,1,7], [4,7,1], [7,4,1], [7,1,4], [2,5,8], [2,8,5], [5,8,2], [5,2,8], [8,5,2], [8,2,5], [3,6,9], [3,9,6], [6,9,3], [6,3,9], [9,6,3], [9,3,6], [4,5,6], [4,6,5], [5,6,4], [5,4,6], [6,5,4], [6,4,5], [7,8,9], [7,9,8], [9,8,7], [9,7,8], [8,7,9], [8,9,7]]
    shipspots1 = random.choice(twoships)
    shipspots2 = random.choice(threeships)

    gameisplaying = True
    while gameisplaying:
        hitboard = [' ' for i in range(10)]
        hitboard2 = [' ' for i in range(10)]
        ship1sp1 = 'true'
        ship1sp2 = 'true'
        ship2sp1 = 'true'
        ship2sp2 = 'true'
        ship3sp2 = 'true'
        while ship1sp1 == 'true':
            userships = []
            sh1sp1 = int(input('What is the first space of your first ship (2 spaces)?'))
            while sh1sp1 not in '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split():
                sh1sp1 = int(input('What is the first space of your first ship (2 spaces)?'))
            userships.append(sh1sp1)
            hitboard2[sh1sp1] = 's'
            ship1sp1 = 'false'

        while ship1sp2 == 'true':
            sh1sp2 = int(input('What is the second space of your first ship (2 spaces)?'))
            while sh1sp2 not in '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split():
                sh1sp2 = int(input('What is the second space of your first ship (2 spaces)?'))
            userships.append(sh1sp2)
            hitboard2[sh1sp2] = 's'
            ship1sp2 = 'false'

        while ship2sp1 == 'true':
            sh2sp1 = int(input('What is the first space of your second ship (2 spaces)?'))
            while sh2sp1 not in '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split():
                sh2sp1 = int(input('What is the first space of your second ship (2 spaces)?'))
            userships.append(sh2sp1)
            hitboard2[sh2sp1] = 's'
            ship2sp1 = 'false'

        while ship2sp2 == 'true':
            sh2sp2 = int(input('What is the second space of your second ship (2 spaces)?'))
            while sh2sp2 not in '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split():
                sh2sp2 = int(input('What is the second space of your first ship (2 spaces)?'))
            userships.append(sh2sp2)
            hitboard2[sh2sp2] = 's'
            ship2sp2 = 'false'

        while ship2sp3 == 'true':
            sh2sp3 = int(input('What is the third space of your second ship (2 spaces)?'))
            while sh2sp3 not in '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split():
                sh2sp3 = int(input('What is the third space of your first ship (2 spaces)?'))
            userships.append(sh2sp3)
            hitboard2[sh2sp3] = 's'
            ship2sp3 = 'false'

        aiturn=True
        while aiturn:
            spot_hit = input('Where\'s the hit?: 1-9  ')
            while not (spot_hit in '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split()):
                spot_hit = input ('Please tell me where the hit is: 1-9  (or Ctrl/Command+C to quit) ')
            spot_hit = int(spot_hit)
            aiships(hitboard, spot_hit, shipspots, hitboard2)
            if 1 == 1:
                gameisplaying = False
                print("PLAYER WINS")

        ai_index += 1

main()
```

**Edit:**
I have added the error checking, but it seems to run in an infinite loop. What is the issue with that?

Comment: Please include a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split your application into two loops; you have combined them together which is the source of your confusion.

The first loop is used to setup the player's ships. This is an infinite loop until all the ships are correctly placed.

Start the loop with a counter, which is the maximum number of ships.

Here is an idea of how this would work

```
user_ships = []  # this will store the ship's coordinates
total_ships = 2 # How many ships a user can have

while len(user_ships) < total_ships:
    coordinates = input('Please enter your ship coordinates: ')
    if check_if_coordinates_are_valid(coordinates):
        if check_if_spot_is_free(coordinates):
            user_ships.append(coordinates)
        else:
            print('Sorry, that spot is already taken by your ship')
    else:
        print('Sorry, those are not valid coordinates')
```

Next, get the computer to place its own ships randomly; its the same idea as the 
user's loop instead you don't print out any error messages and simply go through the random choices until you find a suitable coordinate:

```
computer_ships = []
while len(computer_ships) < total_ships:
    coordinates = random.choice(grid)
    if check_if_spot_is_free(coordinates):
        computer_ships.append(coordinates)
```

Once you have collected both user's ships - store them in a dictionary for easier access later:

```
game_board = {} # an empty dictionary
game_board['player'] = user_ships
game_board['computer'] = computer_ships
```

Now that you have all the ships, you can start you game loop. The condition of this loop is that either user has not sunk the other's fleet.

There are few methods you will use here. The first will be to check if a target has hit the opponent's ship:

```
def check_if_ship_hit(target, user, game_board):
    ships = game_board[user]
    if target not in ships:
        return False, game_board
    else:
        game_board[user][target] = None # Sunk!
        return True, game_board
    return False, game_board
```

The second will check if the user has lost or not:

```
def user_lost(user, game_board):
    ships = game_board[user]
    # If the user has all Nones in his
    # board, he loses
    return sum(1 for i in ships if not i) == len(ships)
```

Once we have those, now we can start our game:

```
player_wins = False
computer_wins = False

while player_wins != True or computer_wins != True:
    # First, its the player's turn:
    target = input('Player, enter a coordinate for the enemy ship: ')
    result, game_board = check_if_ship_hit(target, user='computer', game_board)
    if result:
       print('You scored a hit!')
    else:
       print('You miss!')
    player_wins = user_lost('computer', game_board)

    # Now, the computer's turn
    target = random.choice(grid)
    print('Computer selected a target!')
    result, game_board = check_if_ship_hit(target, user='player', game_board)
    if result:
        print('You are hit!')
    else:
        print('Computer misses!')
    computer_wins = user_lost('player', game_board)
```

Comment: The 5th block of code from the top, is there a more basic way to write it? it seems too pythonic.

Comment: The first 3 code blocks can be placed in a def which can be `userships()` right?

Comment: For error checking, I will leave that up to you (that's what the `check_if_coordinates_are_valid` and `check_if_spot_is_free` methods will do (you'll have to write those yourself). For the fifth block - simply count how many `None` are in the array, if that equals the length of the array, return True, otherwise return False. If you place the first three code blocks in a method, make sure you return the `game_board` dictionary.

Comment: Just to clear things up, i want to put the codes in a function, not a method :)

Comment: In Python, the separation between functions and methods is not as strict as in other languages - often the terms are used as synonyms.

Comment: @BurhanKahlid Please see my edit, I have redesigned parts of it and added the error checking, however it's a problematic one.

Comment: I am planning to use all of the code, but which parts of my code should be deleted, and which should be saved?